ExpressLRS Configurator fails to flash due to a generic error related to checkout
In the ExpressLRS Configurator, I attempted to flash firmware, but it gave a generic error, as pictured:

There were no logs shown, but after hitting BACK and visiting the Logs tab, I found this:

If I change to that directory (cd /Users/nilbus/Library/Application Support/ExpressLRS Configurator/firmwares/binary/ExpressLRS) and run git checkout 3.4.2, it succeeds.

The version of git included with ExpressLRS Configurator (/Applications/ExpressLRS Configurator.app/Contents/dependencies/darwin_amd64/git-2.29.2/bin/git) is older and was incompatible with a configuration I had in ~/.gitconfig.
I discovered this by running git checkout with its git instead of my system git.
❯ cd '/Users/nilbus/Library/Application Support/ExpressLRS Configurator/firmwares/binary/ExpressLRS'

❯ '/Applications/ExpressLRS Configurator.app/Contents/dependencies/darwin_amd64/git-2.29.2/bin/git' checkout 3.4.2
fatal: unknown style 'zdiff3' given for 'merge.conflictstyle'

Sure enough, I'm using a newer conflictstyle configuration that was not supported in the bundled version of git.
❯ grep -B1 zdiff3 ~/.gitconfig
[merge]
  conflictstyle = zdiff3

After commenting this out, the git checkout could succeed, and I was able to proceed with flashing.
